# Duplicate content on pretty urls with htaccess - how to avoid?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up pretty urls with `.htaccess`.

I got it to work, so both `domain.com/contact/` works, and `domain.com/contact.php` still also works. But now there are 2 urls in my domain, with the same content? Can this be avoided? So only `domain.com/contact/` will work?

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)([^./])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^contact/$ /contact.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^contact/$ /contact.php
> ```

You can either block direct access to `/contact.php` or redirect `/contact.php` back to `/contact/` (the canonical URL). The later is generally preferred. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /contact/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [END]
```

Note the addition of the `END` flag (Apache 2.4+) on the existing rewrite to stop *all* further processing (preventing a redirect loop). I've also removed the slash prefix on the substitution string (preferable for internal rewrites).

Since you are rewriting to a file with the same basename as in the requested URL, you need to also make sure that `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) is disabled, otherwise `/contact` (no slash) will also "work" and you could run into issues later (if you want to do more complex rewrites). Alter the `Options` directive at the top of the file like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

However, this isn't particularly scalable. Consider implementing a more generic `/<php-file>` to `/<php-file>.php` rewrite instead. (An exercise for the reader.)